# How to use a "URL" variable to load a webview ? Not using "string" variable

Tags: android

these is how to give a string as argument

String link ="http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl(link);

but how to give an "URL" variable to load its content to webview

I am new to android please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yourURL.toString()` to get String representation of your URL object.

URL link = yourUrl;

webview.loadUrl(yourUrl.toString());